Is this singleton pattern implementation thread safe?
I have an implementation of a Singleton pattern like this, with a very simplified use-case to more easily illustrate what I am trying to do:
import time
import threading
from dataclasses import dataclass

lock = threading.Lock()


class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}  # type: ignore

    def __call__(cls, *args):  # type: ignore
        with lock:
            if cls not in cls._instances:
                cls._instances[cls] = super().__call__(*args)
        return cls._instances[cls]


@dataclass
class Foo(metaclass=Singleton):
    var: bool  # only one variable here, but in my real use-case, there are gonna be many more variables here with more complex interaction between the threads


def change_Foo(signal):  # type: ignore
    foo = Foo(True)
    while True:
        if signal[0]:
            foo.var = not foo.var
            signal[0] = False


def main():  # type: ignore
    foo = Foo(True)
    signal_0 = [False]
    signal_1 = [False]
    threading.Thread(target=change_Foo, args=(signal_0,), daemon=True).start()
    threading.Thread(target=change_Foo, args=(signal_1,), daemon=True).start()

    assert foo.var is True
    signal_0[0] = True
    time.sleep(0.1)
    assert foo.var is False

    signal_1[0] = True
    time.sleep(0.1)
    assert foo.var is True

    signal_0[0] = True
    time.sleep(0.1)
    assert foo.var is False


main()  # type: ignore

The above code implements a singleton pattern using a metaclass as described here. I also combined this with a lock controller as described here.
Is this singleton pattern implementation truly thread safe? If not, what is a thread safe implementation of singleton pattern in python?
I guess with this implementation, the lock is only ever used when creating a new Foo object, but not when accessing a field variable of the class.
Is it possible to apply a lock for when accessing a field member of a class?
I believe I have to overwrite some function like __getitem__() in class Foo (or maybe in class Singleton?) such that when accessing a field variable of Foo, they have to acquire a lock.
Also in my class Singleton implementation I use a global lock, is it possible to make this lock have a local implementation inside of main() instead of having lock be a global variable?
